# How to get the XGraphics Class in PDFsharp

Tags: pdf, pdfsharp

I am using PDFsharp to generate the pdf but I am not able to use the XGraphics class. Can somebody tell me how can I use the XGraphics class or what is the dll and namespace I need to add in my application. Actually I have to draw a line in the header and footer of my dll and on the link http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Draw_simple_lines_0 there is a method DrawLine() which is using the XGraphics class which I am not able to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I got it. It contains under the namespace:

`using PdfSharp.Drawing;`